# Browser does not load updated Laravel blade.php files

Tags: php, laravel

Browser is not loading updated blade.php files no ways. I`m running the project on Ubuntu PC. My Laravel version is 5.4.36.

Here are the things that I have tried so far,

1. Cleared browser cache first
2. Clear project cache using `php artisan cache:clear`.
3. Cleared all the view files that were in `storage/framework/views`.
4. Restarted the project quite number of times, still the same.

The relevant [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206597/chrome-does-not-load-updated-laravel-blade-php-files) that remains, those answers did not help me that is why I had ask to.

Some clue would mean great help. Thank you.

Comment: What are your CACHE_DRIVER and QUEUE_DRIVER variables set to? Could it be related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555783/laravel-5-4-php-artisan-cacheclear-does-not-clear-cache-files-when-using-fil

Comment: In my .env file CACHE_DRIVER=file and QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 - php artisan cache:clear does not clear cache files when using 'file' cache driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555783/laravel-5-4-php-artisan-cacheclear-does-not-clear-cache-files-when-using-fil)

Comment: Sir, I already tried everything those answers have to say.

Comment: What kind of update did you do?

Comment: Is it only happening on chrome? as you mentioned chrome specifically.

Comment: I have edited the question. None of the browsers work actually.

Comment: Check you aren't accidentally making changes in a git branch without committing them